# Extract subset of repository with maven assembly

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Using maven-assembly-plugin version 2.4, I want to build a zip of my repository containing only jar under groupid starting with **mypackage**.

Using repository with pattern **mypackage.*:*** does not work. The build is successful but my repository contains all my dependencies !

```
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <includes>
            <include>mypackage.*:*</include>
        </includes>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <includeMetadata>false</includeMetadata>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Using dependency set with the same pattern works (except all jars are in the root folder ...) :

```
<formats>
  <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<dependencySets>
  <dependencySet>
    <includes>
      <include>mypackage.*:*</include>
    </includes>
    <unpack>false</unpack>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
  </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

Is there something wrong in the configuration ? Is it possible to do that with maven-assembly ?

Comment: Using ``mypackage.**:*`` produces a repository containing only the current POM project : but the flag ``useTransitiveDependencies`` is not available for repositories tag. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

When you specify your assembly using the `repositories` tag, all the dependencies of your project dependencies are imported too, except if you exclude them explicitly in the assembly definition with the tag `excludes`.

For example :

```xml
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <includes>
            <include>mypackage.*:*</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>commons-cli:*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

This will allow you to exclude the dependency *(if your project or one of its dependencies uses it of course)* `commons-cli:*` and its dependencies too, the problem being that you have to list the dependencies you want to exclude but you can easily have a list running `mvn dependency:tree` on your project.