# How to associate an Ant task during mvn assembly:single?

Tags: maven, ant, maven-assembly-plugin

Using the `maven-antrun-plugin` I am able to attach an ant task to a maven phase.

I am using maven assembly plugin without attaching it to any phase : a script is running the command `mvn assembly:single` or `mvn assembly:assembly` when required.

Is there any way I can execute an ant task only when running `mvn assembly:single` ?

PS: this question is related to [Extract subset of repository with maven assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850996/extract-subset-of-repository-with-maven-assembly). As I can't do filtering on repositories produced by assembly plugin, I would like to create an ant task to perform manipulation on the produced repository

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind a plugin to another plugin goal, you can only bind a plugin execution to a phase defined by maven.

[See there : Maven – Guide to Configuring Plug-ins, Configuring Build Plugins](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag).

[Introduction to Maven Lifecycle Reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) or [Maven Core Lifecycle Reference](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3//maven-core/lifecycles.html).

Otherwise instead of lauching only `mvn assembly:single` you can run `mvn antrun:run assembly:single`.